# loop and apply family functions for climate and yield data to calculate correlation

Tags: r, loops, split, sapply

I have a file including around 350 columns; year, temperature for each day , yield for different sites. I need to group or split data by year, then calculate the correlation test between yield and each temperature column one by one. I wrote the script below, however, it produce the results only for one year, is there any suggestion where is the problem/issue (it does not go through each year).

```
for (Y in unique(data_final$YEAR)) {
  # cat ("\n\n YEAR =", Y, "\n =========") # Write year Number
  subData <- data_final [data_final$YEAR == Y,] # Subset the data
  Tmax <- subData[, grepl ("TMAX", colnames (subData))]
  Yield <- subData$YIELD # get YIELD column
  cortest <- list ()
  
  for (i in 1:length (Tmax)) {
  cortest[[i]] <- cor(Tmax[[i]], Yield, use="pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson")
  
  }
  return(do.call ("rbind", cortest))
 }
```

Comment: You erase the previous cortest by assigning an empty list for each year  inside your loop  as I see. Additionaly, why you have a return inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
corrresults <- as.data.frame(unique(data_final$YEAR))
Tmax <- data_final[, grepl ("TMAX", colnames (data_final))]
datasetup <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, nrow=length(YEAR), ncol = length(Tmax)))
corrresults <- cbind(corrresults, datasetup)
colnames(corrresults) <- c("YEAR", seq(1, length(Tmax)))

for (Y in 1:length(YEAR)) {
  
  subData <- data_final[data_final$YEAR == YEAR[Y],] # Subset the data
   
  Tmax <- subData[, grepl ("TMAX", colnames (subData))]
  Yield <- subData$YIELD # get YIELD column
  
  for (i in 1:length (Tmax)) {# Iterate over columns start with Tmax
    cortest <- cor(Tmax[[i]], Yield, use="pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson")
    corrresults[[Y, i+1]] <- cortest
      
  } # end of loop for 
 
} # end of loop for YEAR

write.csv(corrresults, file = "corrresults.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [split, apply, combine](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/plyr.pdf) task to me. So maybe:

```
sp <- split(data_final, data_final$YEAR)
one_year <- function(dset) {
    message("=== year: ", dset[1,"YEAR"], "===")
    # your code
}
res_list <- lapply(sp, one_year)
res <- do.call(rbind, res_list)
```

can do the trick.

The problem with your code seems to be that you use `return` in the outer `for` loop. You would want to collect `cortest` somehow and then enter the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a matrix of correlation between Temp and Yield for Years in your data, you can simply use this functionality of tidyverse and tidymodels.

```r
## Load libraries

library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)


## Load data

data_final <- read.csv("Downloads/data_final_winner.csv")

## Correlation

data_final |> 
  select(-c(1, 348:351, 353)) |> 
  pivot_longer(names_to = "Temp", values_to = "value", cols = 2:346) |> 
  group_by(YEAR, Temp) %>%
  summarize(correlation = cor(YIELD, value)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Temp, values_from = correlation)
```

It should give you the output you are looking.

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>